# Save best score for each level

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically I'm trying to save the best time of each one of my levels, and my code ended up like this:

```
      if(level.CurrentLevel == 1)
    {
        if(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Level1") < timer.TimeLeft)
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Level1", timer.TimeLeft);
    }

    if(level.CurrentLevel == 2)
    {
        if(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Level2") < timer.TimeLeft)
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Level2", timer.TimeLeft);
    }

    if(level.CurrentLevel == 3)
    {
        if(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Level3") < timer.TimeLeft)
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Level3", timer.TimeLeft);
    }

    if(level.CurrentLevel == 4)
    {
        if(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Level4") < timer.TimeLeft)
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Level4", timer.TimeLeft);
    }

    if(level.CurrentLevel == 5)
    {
        if(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Level5") < timer.TimeLeft)
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Level5", timer.TimeLeft);
    }
```

But it is obviously not optimized, so there's some way to make it better? Like using some for loops or something like that?

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 0):

What about simply

```
if (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Level" + level.CurrentLevel) < timer.TimeLeft)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Level" + level.CurrentLevel, timer.TimeLeft);
}
```

Comment: how much data i can store in `PlayerPrefs` is it just a text file under the hood ?

Comment: @Athena See [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) => the only limitation I can spot is 1MB on WebGL